# Starting of tomcat 8.5.12 failed with Netbeans 8.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat8, netbeans-8.1

Good night, I'm trying to run the Tomcat 8.5.12 server from Netbeans 8.1 on a Mac OS SIERRA and it throws me an error **starting of tomcat failed**, in the tomcat log it does not throw errors.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please check , PORT used by tomcat is not occupied. While selecting server in netbeans you have selected correct server. For more please provide more information. You can also try : download new tomcat 9 and try to run code on that.

Comment: Install tomca 9 but I get a bug with netbeans 8.1, apparently this version does not work yet.